# Beaglebone black USB Host - FTDI device no detected

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, usbserial, ftdi

I am working with Beaglebone black device
Trying to have my own compiled Kernel and my own rootfs.
I want to avoid using modules in the kernel, and trying to activate the kernel so it will recognize when I plug in FTDI device to the USB Host.
What is the required kernel configuration items for that? Do I need also to change the DTS file?
It looks I do have the driver since I can see the "usb-serial" when I do "cat /proc/devices", it just that I don't get the device detection.
Here is my dmesg - What do I miss?
`~ # dmesg

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.9.75 (avner@OZC-ThinkPad-E460) (gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) ) #5 PREEMPT Sun Mar 18 22:41:53 IST 2018
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc082] revision 2 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt:Machine model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black
[    0.000000] efi: Getting EFI parameters from FDT:
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 48 MiB at 0x9d000000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 131072
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c0d48df8, node_mem_map dcb61000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 1152 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 131072 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.000000] AM335X ES2.1 (sgx neon)
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 129920
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=PARTUUID=ab08c094-02 rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 456928K/524288K available (8192K kernel code, 301K rwdata, 2476K rodata, 1024K init, 281K bss, 18208K reserved, 49152K cma-reserved, 0K highmem)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xe0800000 - 0xff800000   ( 496 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xe0000000   ( 512 MB)
[    0.000000]     pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0900000   (9184 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc0c00000 - 0xc0d00000   (1024 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc0d00000 - 0xc0d4b618   ( 302 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc0d4b618 - 0xc0d91a8c   ( 282 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 32.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] IRQ: Found an INTC at 0xfa200000 (revision 5.0) with 128 interrupts
[    0.000000] OMAP clockevent source: timer2 at 24000000 Hz
[    0.000012] sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 89478484971ns
[    0.000029] clocksource: timer1: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 79635851949 ns
[    0.000039] OMAP clocksource: timer1 at 24000000 Hz
[    0.000182] clocksource_probe: no matching clocksources found
[    0.000347] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000370] WARNING: Your 'console=ttyO0' has been replaced by 'ttyS0'
[    0.000375] This ensures that you still see kernel messages. Please
[    0.000380] update your kernel commandline.
[    0.000399] Calibrating delay loop... 996.14 BogoMIPS (lpj=4980736)
[    0.089251] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.089372] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.089382] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.090090] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.090429] Setting up static identity map for 0x80100000 - 0x80100058
[    0.091153] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.092307] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.102473] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c rev 3
[    0.102806] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.102830] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
[    0.106099] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.107204] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.108915] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.121642] omap_hwmod: debugss: _wait_target_disable failed
[    0.199240] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.229230] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.233029] gpio gpiochip0: (gpio): added GPIO chardev (254:0)
[    0.233371] gpiochip_setup_dev: registered GPIOs 0 to 31 on device: gpiochip0 (gpio)
[    0.234644] OMAP GPIO hardware version 0.1
[    0.235378] gpio gpiochip1: (gpio): added GPIO chardev (254:1)
[    0.235660] gpiochip_setup_dev: registered GPIOs 32 to 63 on device: gpiochip1 (gpio)
[    0.237375] gpio gpiochip2: (gpio): added GPIO chardev (254:2)
[    0.237731] gpiochip_setup_dev: registered GPIOs 64 to 95 on device: gpiochip2 (gpio)
[    0.239541] gpio gpiochip3: (gpio): added GPIO chardev (254:3)
[    0.239817] gpiochip_setup_dev: registered GPIOs 96 to 127 on device: gpiochip3 (gpio)
[    0.248090] No ATAGs?
[    0.248114] hw-breakpoint: debug architecture 0x4 unsupported.
[    0.286467] edma 49000000.edma: TI EDMA DMA engine driver
[    0.286768] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: can't parse 'gpio' property of node '/fixedregulator0[0]'
[    0.289199] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.289607] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.289886] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.289960] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.290038] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.290398] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: could not find pctldev for node /ocp/l4_wkup@44c00000/scm@210000/pinmux@800/pinmux_i2c0_pins, deferring probe
[    0.290444] omap_i2c 4819c000.i2c: could not find pctldev for node /ocp/l4_wkup@44c00000/scm@210000/pinmux@800/pinmux_i2c2_pins, deferring probe
[    0.290544] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    0.290591] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    0.290627] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.290634] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.290653] PTP clock support registered
[    0.290687] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    0.291628] omap-mailbox 480c8000.mailbox: omap mailbox rev 0x400
[    0.291916] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
[    0.293082] clocksource: Switched to clocksource timer1
[    0.302195] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.302892] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.302939] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.302977] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    0.303038] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.303054] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.303234] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.303630] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.303640] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.303645] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.303650] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.303661] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.304498] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a8 PMU driver, 5 counters available
[    0.306550] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=17 bucket_order=3
[    0.313411] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    0.314242] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.314281] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.314287] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.314328] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O].
[    0.316004] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 247)
[    0.316022] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.316029] io scheduler deadline registered
[    0.316167] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.317342] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins at pa f9e10800 size 568
[    0.318866] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'enable-gpios' property of node '/clk_mcasp0[0]' - status (0)
[    0.371661] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 10 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    0.375222] 44e09000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 158, base_baud = 3000000) is a 8250
[    0.986647] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    0.991699] omap_rng 48310000.rng: OMAP Random Number Generator ver. 20
[    0.998514] [drm] Initialized
[    1.013277] brd: module loaded
[    1.021985] loop: module loaded
[    1.027168] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.103158] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: davinci mdio revision 1.6
[    1.109297] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: detected phy mask fffffffe
[    1.116434] libphy: 4a101000.mdio: probed
[    1.120476] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: phy[0]: device 4a101000.mdio:00, driver SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720
[    1.130383] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: Detected MACID = 98:5d:ad:b5:f6:fe
[    1.138534] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.145246] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.149802] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    1.155258] ehci-omap: OMAP-EHCI Host Controller driver
[    1.160597] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.166881] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    1.172327] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.178496] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[    1.184408] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[    1.190996] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[    1.197073] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[    1.202870] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[    1.210713] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.216667] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.221376] /cpus/cpu@0: unsupported enable-method property: ti,am3352
[    1.228169] CPUidle arm: CPU 0 failed to init idle CPU ops
[    1.234379] omap_hsmmc 48060000.mmc: GPIO lookup for consumer cd
[    1.234388] omap_hsmmc 48060000.mmc: using device tree for GPIO lookup
[    1.234411] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'cd-gpios' property of node '/ocp/mmc@48060000[0]' - status (0)
[    1.234473] omap_hsmmc 48060000.mmc: Got CD GPIO
[    1.239119] omap_hsmmc 48060000.mmc: GPIO lookup for consumer wp
[    1.239124] omap_hsmmc 48060000.mmc: using device tree for GPIO lookup
[    1.239130] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: can't parse 'wp-gpios' property of node '/ocp/mmc@48060000[0]'
[    1.239135] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: can't parse 'wp-gpio' property of node '/ocp/mmc@48060000[0]'
[    1.239140] omap_hsmmc 48060000.mmc: using lookup tables for GPIO lookup
[    1.239147] omap_hsmmc 48060000.mmc: lookup for GPIO wp failed
[    1.293627] omap_hsmmc 481d8000.mmc: GPIO lookup for consumer cd
[    1.293638] omap_hsmmc 481d8000.mmc: using device tree for GPIO lookup
[    1.293646] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: can't parse 'cd-gpios' property of node '/ocp/mmc@481d8000[0]'
[    1.293652] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: can't parse 'cd-gpio' property of node '/ocp/mmc@481d8000[0]'
[    1.293657] omap_hsmmc 481d8000.mmc: using lookup tables for GPIO lookup
[    1.293662] omap_hsmmc 481d8000.mmc: lookup for GPIO cd failed
[    1.293669] omap_hsmmc 481d8000.mmc: GPIO lookup for consumer wp
[    1.293674] omap_hsmmc 481d8000.mmc: using device tree for GPIO lookup
[    1.293678] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: can't parse 'wp-gpios' property of node '/ocp/mmc@481d8000[0]'
[    1.293683] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: can't parse 'wp-gpio' property of node '/ocp/mmc@481d8000[0]'
[    1.293688] omap_hsmmc 481d8000.mmc: using lookup tables for GPIO lookup
[    1.293768] omap_hsmmc 481d8000.mmc: lookup for GPIO wp failed
[    1.353552] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'gpios' property of node '/leds/led2[0]' - status (0)
[    1.353720] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'gpios' property of node '/leds/led3[0]' - status (0)
[    1.353841] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'gpios' property of node '/leds/led4[0]' - status (0)
[    1.353939] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'gpios' property of node '/leds/led5[0]' - status (0)
[    1.354305] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.366458] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.372155] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    1.379129] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.383963] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.388489] omap_voltage_late_init: Voltage driver support not added
[    1.408210] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    1.422583] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[    1.428797] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SC16G 14.8 GiB 
[    1.437325] random: fast init done
[    1.441165]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    1.447772] tps65217 0-0024: TPS65217 ID 0xe version 1.2
[    1.453819] at24 0-0050: 32768 byte 24c256 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
[    1.461592] mmc1: new high speed MMC card at address 0001
[    1.468607] mmcblk1: mmc1:0001 M62704 3.56 GiB 
[    1.473519] mmcblk1boot0: mmc1:0001 M62704 partition 1 2.00 MiB
[    1.479716] mmcblk1boot1: mmc1:0001 M62704 partition 2 2.00 MiB
[    1.486999]  mmcblk1: p1
[    1.605393] tda998x 0-0070: found TDA19988
[    1.610856] tilcdc 4830e000.lcdc: bound 0-0070 (ops tda998x_ops)
[    1.616953] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.623608] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[    1.629869] tilcdc 4830e000.lcdc: No connectors reported connected with modes
[    1.637078] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes - going 1024x768
[    1.651196] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
[    1.662392] tilcdc 4830e000.lcdc: fb0:  frame buffer device
[    1.693112] [drm] Initialized tilcdc 1.0.0 20121205 on minor 0
[    1.699040] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: bus 0 rev0.11 at 400 kHz
[    1.823914] omap_i2c 4819c000.i2c: bus 2 rev0.11 at 100 kHz
[    1.831120] hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[    1.836809] ALSA device list:
[    1.839801]   No soundcards found.
[    1.897085] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
[    1.902983] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    1.911223] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:2.
[    1.922864] devtmpfs: mounted
[    1.927115] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K
[    2.306710] export_store: invalid GPIO 246
~ # `
```

Thanks

Avner

Comment: For USB devices you don't need to modify the devicetree. Check `dmesg` include output into your question. Just usb-serial is not sufficient, you also need the chip specific module built into your kernel.

Comment: I added the dmesg , do you what is missing?

Comment: I can see the ftdi driver coming up at `1.202870`. I don't see any mention of `musb-hdrc`. Are you missing the USB controller driver? Also the BBB has multiple UARTs, why use a FTDI USB2serial in the first place?

Comment: This is what my customer has, but anyway, I resolved it (I put the answer) and thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue (Thanks to TI support):
Use arch/arm/configs/tisdk_am335x-evm_defconfig as the base config - copy it to .config
run "make config"
remove "Enable loadable module support"
Then:
Device Drivers  ---> [*] USB support  ---> <*>   USB Serial Converter support  ---> USB FTDI Single Port Serial Driver <*>
Save and Exit, and build the kernel
Use "am335x-boneblack.dts" for DTB
I am using this kernel and dtb with my own rootfs and it identify FTDI device connect

Good Luck
Avner

Comment: Well, you seem to have switched to a completely different defconfig. Not surprised it works with that.